# Wrong? My typesets: $F_{\rho}(A) \subseteq \F_{\rho}(\mathbf{G})$

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, math-operators

This is what I want: [image], except the right hand side, where the operator should be **`$F_{\rho}`**, and you get it.

The typesets I tried are: `$F_{\rho}(A) \subseteq \F_{\rho}(\mathbf{G})$`, with the output appears as the image as above.

Can anyone know how to fix it? Thank you:-)

Comment: There is a typo on `\F_{\rho}`. Must be without \ in "F".

Comment: The (horribly formatted) error you see is saying that `\F` is undefined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As from my comment here there is the correct MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$F_{\rho}(A) \subseteq F_{\rho}(\mathbf{G})$.
\end{document}
```

[image]